# Levenshtein Distance-like algorithm for diffing in-memory objects?

Tags: java, algorithm, diff, levenshtein-distance

Java 8 here, though this answer should apply to any lang.

I have a problem where I need to compare to objects, say, `Widgets`, and produce a "diff" between them: that is, a set of steps that, if followed, will transform one `Widget` (the *source*) into the other (the *target*).

```
class Widget {
    // Properties and such.
}

class WidgetDiffer extends Differ<Widget> {
    List<Transformation> diff(Widget source, Widget target) {
        // The produced list will convert source to target, if executed
        // by some runtime.
    }
}

class WidgetTransformer extends Transformer<Widget> {
    @Override
    Widget transformSourceToTarget(Widget source, List<Transformation> transforms) {
        // Somehow, run 'transforms' on 'source', which *should*
        // produce an object with the same state/properties as
        // the original target.
    }
}
```

I am aware of the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm for string transformations, but:

- That's just for strings, not `Widgets`; and
- It only gives you an integer (# of transformations required to turn the sink into the target), whereas I need a `List<Transformation>` that, when executed by some engine, turns source to target

I'm wondering if there are any known algorithms for doing this type of operations. Any chance these algorithms live in a library somewhere?!?

Comment: Can you convert both to json or xml and diff the strings?

Comment: Thanks @LanceJava (+1) - I can do anything, just wondering if there were standard algorithms for this type of thing, and secretly hoping someone in the JVM-space has already solved/implemented them :-)

Answer (score 1):

I see it as a search problem. Construct a graph where the destination node is the desired widget and the start node is the widget to be transformed. Each step (edge in the graph) represents one possible transformation to the widget (adding or removing properties). Once the graph is constructed run DFS with path-extraction on it and you will get the steps  needed to transform the starting widget into the desired one (it will also be the minimum ammount of steps needed).

Comment: Thanks @Shanded (+1) - thats certainly an interesting idea, and one I'd consider. **However**, three issues with it right off the bat: (1) the graph would be *massive*, especially if `Widget` has `double` or `string` properties (how many possible values for doubles and strings are there?!?!), (2) how would this alg handle a case where `Widget` itself contain child objects?, and (3) you'd need some way of verifying/guaranteeing that each path from source to target does in fact produce the target, and not something else.

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking for the algorithm here, just whether or not known algorithms solve this problem, what they are, and whether they're implemented in Java yet. Thanks again!

Comment: What if we consider the transformation to be just adding/removing given property (without it's value), the values are given in the destination node.

Answer (score 0):

If the widgets are just key->value bags than the problem is pretty simple.

Here's a JavaScript (you could use it as pseudo code for the Java implementation) version.

```
function diff(src, target) {
  var result = [];
  for(var key in src) {
    if(key in target) { 
      if(src[key] !== target[key]) {
        result.push({op:"update", name:key, value:target[key]});
      }
    } else {
      result.push({op:"delete", name:key});
    }
  }
  for(var key in target) {
    if(!(key in src)) {
      result.push({op:"add", name:key, value:target[key]});
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(diff({}, {a:1, b:2, c:3})));
console.log(JSON.stringify(diff({a:1, b:2, c:3}, {})));
console.log(JSON.stringify(diff({a:1, b:2, c:3}, {b:20, c:30, d:40})));
```

O(srcPropCount * lookupTargetProp + targetPropCount * lookupSrcPropCount)

The only operations are Add a new property, Update an existing property, and Delete a property.